# Problem with checking whether $x(t)$ can be a solution of any system of first order homogeneous ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find out whether $$x(t) = (3e^t + e^{-t}, e^{2t})$$ can be a solution of the system $$\dot{x} = A x\quad \quad (1)$$, where $A$ is a $2x2$ matrix. I'm not sure of my solution, which is the following:

We know that the solution of $(1)$ is given by:

$$x(t) = exp(At)\space x_0$$where $x_0$ are our initial conditions. So I get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}3e^t+e^{-t} \\ e^{2t} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}e^t & e^{-t}\\ 0 & e^{2t}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now to my opinion this is not possible, since the fact that the elements $_{11}$ and $_{22}$ of the matrix $exp(At)$ are $e^t$, $e^{2t}$ which suggests me that the matrix $A$ has two different eigenvalues $\implies$ $A$ is diagonalizable $\implies$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\implies exp(At) \neq \begin{pmatrix}e^t & e^{-t}\\ 0 & e^{2t}\end{pmatrix}$.

Am i right? If not could you give me a hint on how to work to find out the solution?

P.S. This exercise is part of an exercise of [this](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf) book at page 73

Comment: Why all the $e^{At}$ business? Just compute $\dot x$ and compare to $Ax$...

Comment: What is $A{{}}$?

Comment: @fgp I need to solve it this way, without computing it explicitly

Comment: @GitGud I think it is the point of the problem: find $A$ such that $exp(At) = \begin{pmatrix}e^t & e^{-t} \\ 0 & e^{2t} \end{pmatrix}$. In my solution I think I've proven that such matrix does not exists

Comment: @Ale Ah, OK, so the question should be "Show that $x$ cannot be the solution of *any* 2-dimensional linear homogenous ODE".

Comment: @fgp I actually don't know if it is a solution or not

Comment: @Ale Ok, so then "Check wheter $x$ is the solution of *any* ...". The point is, the way you wrote your question, one is lead to believe that $A$ is known...

Comment: @fgp Thank you, it should be fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}3e^t+e^{-t} \\ e^{2t} \end{pmatrix} = e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+e^{t}\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
One only gets exponential factors from the eigenvalues of the system matrix, i.e., the roots of its characteristic equation. No (truly) quadratic polynomial has three different roots.

Another hint is that the eigenspaces of the different eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$ would be identical.